# Best way of reading & processing a text file

Tags: c#, performance, text, stream, csv

Was wondering if anyone had any favourite methods/ useful libraries for processing a tab-delimited text file? This file is going to have on average 30,000 - 50,000 rows in it. Just need to read through each row and throw it into a database. However, i'd need to temporarily store all the data, the reason being that if the table holding the data gets to more than 1,000,00 rows, i'll need to create a new table and put the data in there. The code will be run in a windows service so i'm not worried about processing time.

Was thinking about just doing a standard while(sr.ReadLine()) ... any suggestions?

Cheers,

Sean.

Comment: For the record, you don't need to load it all into memory, if that's the ONLY reason. You can just keep a running total as you go of how many records have been processed.

Comment: Well each time data is uploaded it gets assigned a batch number, so if the latest batch plus the current table total > 1,000,000, i'd want to create a new table and put the data in there, keeping batches together, so when i come to use the data on the front-end, i would only have to select from one table...

Comment: since one of the answers got deleted with my comments: A simple sr.ReadLine() won't cut it since there can be fields which are doublequoted. When they are, they can contain special characters like the delimiter itself, or a newline character. So reading newlines can be done, but just beware that reading one newline doesn't mean you get the whole row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) is very flexible and fast. I never get tired recommending it. Defaults to ',' as a delimiter, but you can change it to '\t' easily.

Comment: the delimiter is given as a parameter in this library, so this is a non issue

Comment: That's what I meant with "change it easily" :)

Answer (score 3):

[filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/default.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect "throwing it into a database" will take at least 1 order of magnitude longer than reading a line into a buffer, so you could pre-scan the data just to count the number of rows (without parsing them). Then make your database decisions. Then re-read the data doing the real work. With luck, the OS will have cached the file so it reads even quicker.